# Searching and Sorting Multiple Files

Tags: c#

Need to Search through 6 txt files and then sort them together. Any starting ideas?

Comment: You should post what you've tried so far so that others can advise you.

Comment: Is this a homework assignment? I second what ManoDestra said, post what you've tried

Comment: @cost Perhaps not, this format seems just convoluted enough to be an official government data format

Comment: "I need to give the user the option to either search for a year and bring all the corresponding data back (from each file, on the same line number) or the same but search for months" This is really too broad for a Stack Overflow question. You can write at least some of this yourself, assuming you wrote the code you posted. Get as far as you can. Prompt the user for which type of search, and what the search string is. Then when they search, just return all the data. Then think about how to filter out the data that doesn't match the search. Ask about that if you get stuck.

Answer (score 1):

If I assume that your data is already sorted in ascending order and your user input will be year and month. For example, they would like to see the weather data for 2014 July, then you can use the index of the array as the same line number indicator. Please look at the following code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string yearInput = "2014"; // User input
    string monthInput = "July"; // User input

    string[] Year = { "2013", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2015" };
    string[] Month = { "July", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December", "January" };
    string[] rain1 = { "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7" };
    string[] sun1 = { "0a", "1a", "2a", "3a", "4a", "5a", "6a", "7a" };

    var yearIndex = Array.FindIndex(Year, year => year == yearInput);
    var monthIndex = Array.FindIndex(Month, yearIndex, month => month == monthInput);

    var outputRain = rain1[monthIndex]; // The corresponding rain for the input
    var outputSun = sun1[monthIndex]; // The corresponding sun for the input
}
```

`Array.FindIndex` From the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.findindex%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), is to `searches for an element that matches the conditions defined by a specified predicate, and returns the zero-based index of the first occurrence within an Array or a portion of it.`

From there, we could find the index of the first occurence of specified year and use it as `startIndex` to search for the index of the specified month so it will skip the year 2013 and start the operation from year 2014.

After we get the `monthIndex`, from my assumption, we could treat that as line number and get the weather data. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you, help a lot!! Sorry to bother you but is there any way to make it so it will do the same but for every occurrence?

Comment: Could you explain what do you mean by every occurence?